# How to apply an Array to a sort in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, sorting

The script below highlights an array B4:F9.

I then want to replace Ranges (B4:B9) and (B4:F9) with the array, so I can sort the array.

This array changes depending on the number of rows/columns of the array.

```
Sub Macro6()

'Highlights the array
    Range("B4").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
'
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
        "B4:B9"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Sort
        .SetRange Range("B4:F9")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you need! Try and let us know.

```
Sub SortSheet1()
    Dim keyRng As Range
    
    ' key range
    Set keyRng = Range(Range("B4"), Range("B4").End(xlDown))
    Debug.Print keyRng.Address
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 _
        Key:=keyRng, _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
        Order:=xlAscending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Elio, much appreciated!

Comment: @user11797977, if it was useful don't forget to check it!